# Arduino Yun connection problems

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun

I followed this [guide](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun) and evertything works until I'm at chapter [Configuring the onboard WiFi](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc16).

I can see the arduino as an AP.

[image: Arduino Yun Acces point]

And I can connect with it. However when entering the IP adress *192.168.240.1* or *arduino.local* it does not give me the login page. 
When using the IP adress I get: the site is not accessable screen. Using *arduino.local* gives me a page that loads forever for a long time before giving me the exact same result.

[image: Page not loading]

I have looked on different forums for a solution. [This one](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=188101.msg1554795#msg1554795) said that I should download bonjour and bonjour browser because they use the same port (port 5353). After installing the bonjour browser I should be seeing a connection called .arduino._tcp but I don't see that. In fact I often can't see any connection what so ever.

[image: Bonjour browser 1]

and sometimes I can see a few connections but none of those are the arduino.

[image: Bonjour browser 2]

I have tried to ping with the arduino on the adress *192.168.240.1* but all I got was a time out.

```
Pinging 192.168.240.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

**Edit** : I managed to get the bonjour browser to work all the time, by installing itunes. It also shows the arduino.

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that your computer has been given a correct IP address on the right subnet through DHCP?

Comment: Yes i have checked that. also i just tried to do it on another computer and it seems to work with that computer.

Comment: So this is a problem with your computer then, not the Yun. I suggest disabling *all* firewalls and antivirus products and trying again.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of WI-FI connection properties. You must be connected to the `Arduino-Yun` network and not `WiFi-2.4-2348_EXT`.

Comment: @AltAir i replaced the screenshot

Comment: @Majenko I disabled all firewalls and disabled my antivirus, still didn't manage to load the page

Answer (score 1):

You have to find IP address of your Yùn on your local network. 
What I do in this case: 
- look on the Home router if you can see your Yùn and it's ip, or,
- there is a sketch in Arduino Ide / exemple / bridge / wifi status which can help you to get ip, or
-  open the Arduino Ide software, upload serialTerminal sketch and open serial monitor. It allows you to access the Linux part of the Yùn and type 'ifconfig' to get the IP from the Yùn.

Comment: Well as you can see on the last screenshot I made the ip is 192.168.240.1